# How to limit values for oninput calculation without limiting the input values?

Tags: html, forms

How can one limit the output values, say, from 5 to 195. without limiting the input values?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">0
<input type="range" id="a" value="50">100 +
<input type="number" id="b" value="50">=
<output name="x" for="a b"></output>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form oninput="var n = parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value); x.value =  n < 5 ? 5 : ( n > 195 ? 195 : n);">0
<input type="range" id="a" value="50">100 +
<input type="number" id="b" value="50">=
<output name="x" for="a b"></output>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This uses a nested trinary opertor `a ? b : c` which is essentially `a if b else c`. When it's nested you can think of it like this: `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` as `a if b ELSE (c if d else e)` as the result of `(c ? d : e)` is the equivalent of `c` in `a ? b : c`.

Try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UvZDk/)

Alternativley, you could do

```
<form oninput="x.value = Math.min(Math.max(5,parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)),195);"/>
```

Which achieves the same result, just in a different way, you can play with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uQwuh/)

Try it out here:
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UvZDk/)

Comment: Thank you HennyH! Both solution works and thanks for the explaining nested Ternary Operator.